# Compare and validate two strings

Tags: c#, string, validation

```
// A = Alphabetic, X = Alphanumeric, N = Numeric character

string strForMatching = "AAAAXXXX-NNNN-AA";

string[] strToBeValidated = new string[]
{
    "333TEST",
    "TEST4444-1234-AB",
    "ABCD12AB-1234-99",
    "ABCD2345-1234-AB",
    "PPP12AA-9876"
};
```

With a `for` loop I am passing each string from string array to this method

```
public bool ValidateString(string strForMatching, string strToBeValidated)
{
    bool isValid = false;

    // what to put here?

    return isValid;
}
```

I want to validate `strToBeValidated` with `strForMatching`.

That means:

- `333TEST` is not valid
- `ABCD2345-1234-AB` is valid
- `PPP12AA-9876` is valid
- `PPPPP12AX-1234-AB` is not valid.

What ever value is there should match with `strForMatching`. I also need to validate the separator.

I can not use regular expression because I have `AAAAXXX-NNNN-AA`, in my case 1 to 4 alphabet is okay it is valid but more than 4 alphabet is not valid same as for X and N and Separate can be change it could be `/ or # or @` anything. If i'll use regular Expression then it will check till fix length

Comment: try using regular expressions: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression

Comment: I am using windows application

Comment: `I am using windows application` So? just use [`System.Text.RegularExpressions`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.aspx) in your windows application. They are not mutually exclusive.

Comment: Here's a Regex to help you out: `@"\w{4}(\w|\d){4}-\d{4}-\w{2}"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regular expression seems to work as expected

```
string[] strTobeValidate = new string[] {"333TEST", "TEST4444-1234-AB", "ABCD12AB-1234-99", "ABCD2345-1234-AB", "PPP12AA-9876" };
Regex r = new Regex(@"[A-Za-z]{4}[A-Za-z0-9]{4}-[0-9]{4}-[A-Za-z]{2}");
foreach(string s in strTobeValidate)
{
    Match m = r.Match(s);
    if(m.Success == false)
        Console.WriteLine("No match for: " + s);
    else
        Console.WriteLine(m.ToString());

}
```

**Meaning:**

- First set of four characters `{4}` should be in the range A-Z (upper
  case) or a-z (lower case)
- The second set of four character should be as before but could also
  contains numbers 0-9
- A minus symbol will follow
- The third set of four characters are just numbers
- A minus symbol will follow
- The fourth set of 2 characters are just alphabetich characters

Now applying the Regex pattern to your input strings you find a match only for the second and fourth string.

Looking at the comment I have tried to build a simple pattern builder.

```
string BuildPattern(string h)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    string curPattern = "";
    char curChar = ' ';
    int cnt = 0;
    foreach(Char c in h)
    {
        if(c != curChar && cnt != 0)
        {
            sb.Append(curPattern);
            sb.Append("{" + cnt.ToString() + "}");
            cnt = 0;
            curPattern = "";
        }
        curChar = c;
        switch(c)
        {
            case 'A':
                curPattern = "[A-Za-z]";
                cnt++;
                break;
            case 'X':
                curPattern = "[A-Za-z0-9]";
                cnt++;
                break;
            case 'N':
                curPattern = "[0-9]";
                cnt++;
                break;
            default:
                sb.Append(c);
                break;
        }
    }
    sb.Append(curPattern);
    sb.Append("{" + cnt.ToString() + "}");
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

And change the code that prepare the Regex pattern with this one:

```
string strForMatching = "AAAANNAA-NNNN-NN";
string pattern = BuildPattern(strForMatching);
// Fixed -> Regex r = new Regex(@"[A-Za-z]{4}[A-Za-z0-9]{4}-[0-9]{4}-[A-Za-z]{2}");
// Dynamic pattern 
Regex r = new Regex(pattern);
```

However this need to be tested more extensively......

Comment: you could also use `if(r.IsMatch(s))`

Comment: if the next time I will get some other string in strForMatching something like AAAA-XXXX or XXX-NNNN-AA or NNN-AA-XXX. I don't want to keep anything hard coded. In my scenario I have a combobox user select value from the combobox that value is strForMatching

Comment: If the nature of the match is dynamic as your comment implies then you need to build the pattern dynamically. You could translate your A, N and X to the respective Regex patterns (A-Za-z) and so on, then count the occurrence of A,N and X to define the number of allowed characters {x}. As you can see, an exaustive work is not an easy task.

Comment: @Steve: I have AAAAXXX-NNNN-AA, in my case 1 to 4 alphabet is okay it is valid but more than 4 alphabet is not valid same as for X and N and Separate can be change it could be / or # or @ anything. If i'll use regular Expression then it will check till fix length

Comment: If i am going to compare exact value then its working nice.. Thanks Steve your ans. gave me some idea

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to be built dynamically, then I'd just avoid regular expressions altogether. Build some objects to do the work for you.

First a very simple class just to validate a single character with an arbitrary matching check:

```
public class Matcher
{
    public char Flag { get; private set; }
    private readonly Predicate<char> Checker;

    public Matcher(char flag, Predicate<char> checker)
    {
        this.Flag = flag;
        this.Checker = checker;
    }

    public bool DoesMatch(char character)
    {
        return Checker(character);
    }
}
```

Then some validation class that does the heavy lifting:

```
public class StringValidator
{
    private Dictionary<char, Matcher> Matchers = new Dictionary<char, Matcher>();

    public StringValidator()
    {
        Matchers = new[]{
            new Matcher('A', c => Char.IsLetter(c)),
            new Matcher('N', c => Char.IsDigit(c)),
            new Matcher('X', c => Char.IsLetter(c) || Char.IsDigit(c)),
            new Matcher('-', c => c == '-')}
            .ToDictionary(m => m.Flag);
    }

    public bool ValidateString(string strForMatching, string strTobeValidated)
    {
        if (strForMatching.Length != strTobeValidated.Length)
            return false;

        for(int i = 0; i < strTobeValidated.Length; i++)
        {
            Matcher matcher = GetMatcher(strForMatching[i]);

            if (!matcher.DoesMatch(strTobeValidated[i]))
                return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    private Matcher GetMatcher(char flag)
    {
        Matcher matcher;

        if(!Matchers.TryGetValue(flag, out matcher))
            throw new IndexOutOfRangeException(String.Format("No matcher for character '{0}'", flag));

        return matcher;
    }
}
```

Now how you go about choosing to create the matching routines or organize them, or their flags is up to you. In this case the `StringValidator` has its rules "hard-coded", but you can change that to pass them in via the constructor or changed via public methods.

Also, the rules I'm using [`Char.IsLetter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yyxz6h5w.aspx) and [`Char.IsDigit`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7f0ddtxh.aspx) which goes a bit beyond simple "A-Z" and "0-9", but it should be enough to demonstrate how it works. Feel free to replace those specific checks with a regex or other check if you wish.

Also, your example rules/outputs seemed off (for example, I'd expect "PPP12AA-9876" to *not* match against "AAAAXXXX-NNNN-AA"). This currently checks if the lengths match, but you can get rid of that. And if the matching pattern is shorter than the input to validate (or vice versa) I wasn't positive about so I'll leave that to you as an exercise based on your exact requirements.

Some sample usage:

```
string[] stringsToValidate = new string[] { 
                                       "333TEST",
                                       "TEST4444-1234-AB",
                                       "ABCD12AB-1234-99",
                                       "ABCD2345-1234-AB",
                                       "PPP12AA-9876"
                                   };
string strForMatching = "AAAAXXXX-NNNN-AA";

var validator = new StringValidator();

foreach(var strToValidate in stringsToValidate)
{
    bool isValid = validator.ValidateString(strForMatching, strToValidate);
    Console.WriteLine(strToValidate + ": " + isValid);
}
```

Outputs:

> 333TEST: False
>   TEST4444-1234-AB: True
>   ABCD12AB-1234-99: False
>   ABCD2345-1234-AB: True
>   PPP12AA-9876: False

Comment: last value is showing False but in my case it should be true, stringsToValidate can be less than or equal to strForMatching but It must not greater than the strForMatching

Comment: @Rocky But it also only has 3 "P" characters at the start. If it were to match, even if shorter, shouldn't it have 4 "P"? Or does it not matter if it's trimmed from the start or end? Either way, it should be easy for you to cover in `ValidateString` method.

Comment: I have AAAAXXX-NNNN-AA, in my case 1 to 4 alphabet is okay it is valid but more than 4 alphabet is not valid same as for X and N and Separate can be change it could be / or # or  @ anything

Comment: Oh, I didn't realize "AAAA" meant "up to 4 letters". Well, this solution isn't going to lend itself well to that. Maybe stick with the regex builder Steve provided. EDIT: Does that mean "P", "PP", "P1" are all valid combinations too?